# Returning hidden object with Angular ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive, watch

I am trying to show the first value of a group and hide all other similar values within an ng-repeat.  I  am getting the if/else to work but it's literally returning "false" as a string.  Here is what I have so far.

```
app.filter('dateSort', function() {
  var prevVal = null;
  return function(input) {
    if (prevVal !== input.uniquedate) {
      prevVal = input.uniquedate;
      return moment(input.jsdatetime).format('dddd,\n MMMM Do');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

});

I've also tried this as a directive, but with no luck.

```
app.directive('hideon', function() {
var prevVal = $index[-1].uniquedate;
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.hideon, function(value, oldValue) {
        if(element.uniquedate !== prevVal) {
            element.show();
        } else {
            element.hide();
        }
    }, true);
}
```

});

Any help is appreciated.  I am assuming that the best way to do this is with a directive.  For the filter itself with the returned objects (including the false), the values don't hold after I sort any of the data.  That's when I started trying to use it with $watch.

Here's a Codepen with what I've started- http://codepen.io/drewbietron/pen/dKjhe

Comment: does ngHide/ngShow/ngIf not work?

Comment: @TheSharpieOne I've tried multiple versions of this with no success.  The filter function works but it doesn't update after a filter has been called.  I also need the element to completely disappear form the DOM since that element has CSS padding to it - a blank box still shows just with no content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix to blank box display.

```
app.filter('uniqueDate', function() {
 var prevVal = null, prevSeq = null;
 return function(input, seq) {
   input.show = false;
   if (prevVal !== input.month || prevSeq == seq-1) {
     prevVal = input.month;
     input.show = true;
     return input.day + " " + input.month;
   }
 };
});
```

Have made code changes to filter the events on selecting types.

```
      var selectedTypes = ["Math", "Science", "Writing"];
      $scope.updateSelectedTypes = function(type){
        var found = _.some(selectedTypes, function(selType){
          return selType == type;
        });
        if(!found){
          selectedTypes.push(type);
        }
        else{
          selectedTypes = _.difference(selectedTypes, type);
        }
        filterEvents();
      };

      var filterEvents = function(){
        var result = _.filter(Events, function(event){
          return _.some(selectedTypes, function(type){
            return event.type == type;
          });
        });

        result = _.each(result, function(item){
          item.show = false;
        });
        $scope.events = angular.copy(result);
      };
```

HTML:

```
<li><b>Filter By:</b></li>
<li class="filter" ng-click="updateSelectedTypes('Math')" ng-class="{ active: Math }">Math</li>
<li class="filter" ng-click="updateSelectedTypes('Science')" ng-class="{ active: Science }">Science</li>
<li class="filter"  ng-click="updateSelectedTypes('Writing')" ng-class="{ active: Writing}">Writing</li>
<input type="search" ng-model="instructor.instructor" placeholder="Search By Instructor..." />
```

Here is the updated codepen [link](http://codepen.io/pailas/pen/bqird/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, couldn't spend time on it yesterday.